# Pandas: compute mean and std within [25 percentile and 75 percentile]

Tags: pandas

I have the following code which computes some aggregations for my data frame:

```
def percentile(n):
    def percentile_(x):
        return np.percentile(x, n)
    percentile_.__name__ = 'percentile_%s' % n
    return percentile_

df_type = df[['myType', 'required_time']].groupby(['myType']).agg(['count', 'min', 'max', 'median', 'mean', 'std',  percentile(25), percentile(75)])
```

The code works fine. However, now I want to compute mean and std just using the data within [25 percentile and 75 percentile], what would be the most elegant way in Pandas to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using quantile and describe, is this works for yours

```
df[['myType', 'required_time']].groupby(['myType']).quantile([0.25,0.5]).describe()
```

Out:

```
    RandomForestClassifier  AdaBoostClassifier  GaussianNB
count   2.000000    2.000000    2.000000
mean    0.596761    0.627393    0.580476
std 0.496570    0.463766    0.491389
min 0.245632    0.299462    0.233012
25% 0.421196    0.463427    0.406744
50% 0.596761    0.627393    0.580476
75% 0.772325    0.791359    0.754208
max 0.947889    0.955325    0.927941
```